# Avoiding nested let

Tags: kotlin

I have a case of multiple nested `let` and I was wondering if those could be simplified in a more idiomatic way.
Example:

```
fun process(person: Person) {
    if(isManager(person)) {
        person.metadata?.let {
            it.personalInfo?.let {
                if(it.firstLine) {
                    if(it.positions.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        foo()
                    }
                    else {
                        bar()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        person.metadata?.let {
            it.personalInfo?.let {
                if(it.firstLine && !it.positions.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        baz()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Setting aside the actual logic as this is just an example, is there a more idiomatic way to write this and avoid the nested let?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use chain of `?.` operators instead of `.`. And call `let` only on the last statement.

```
person.metadata?.personalInfo?.let {
    // logic here
}
```

Here is my proposal how to simplify entire method

```
fun process(person: Person) {
    val personalInfo = person.metadata?.personalInfo ?: return
    if (!personalInfo.firstLine) {
        return
    }

    val positionsEmpty = personalInfo.positions.isNullOrEmpty()
    if (isManager(person)) {
        if (positionsEmpty) foo() else bar()
    } else if (!positionsEmpty) {
        baz()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I still need to do conditional branches. So how would that simplify things?

Comment: I don't see any branches on the `let` statement (by branch I mean if-else with elvis operator), so using null-safe calls will reduce nesting, thus simplify the code. If you want to simplify it more, you can make some checks at the beginning of the method and return for some cases.

Comment: @Jim you have to expand on that because this is the solution

Answer (score 1):

I would pull the indirect properties into local variables. Local variables allow you to avoid the `?.let` pattern because they can be smart-cast to non-nullables by checking if they are null with `if`.

But in this particular case, you aren't doing anything in any branch when `metadata` or `personalInfo` is null, so you can do an early return on null and then you don't even need smart-casting.

```
fun process(person: Person) {
    val personalInfo = person.metaData?.personalInfo ?: return
    if(isManager(person)) {
        if(personalInfo.firstLine) {
            if(personalInfo.positions.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                foo()
            }
        else {
            bar()
        }
    } else if (personalInfo.firstLine && !personalInfo.positions.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        baz()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `notnull` check to avoid nested `let`

possible solution

```
fun process(person: Person) {
    if(isManager(person) && (person.metadata != null) &&(person.metadata.personalInfo != null)) {
      
                    if(person.metadata.personalInfo.first.positions.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        foo()
                    }
                    else {
                        bar()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
       if( person.metadata.personalInfo)
       {
                if(person.metadata.personalInfo.firstLine && !person.metadata.personalInfo.positions.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        baz()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```